# sendMail Function Limited Characters?

Tags: php, function, email

I have a sendMail PHP function and it works, but as long as I try a longer message, it stops to work. Any ideas for why this happens ?

```
function send_mail($from,$to,$subject,$body)
{
    $headers = '';
    $headers .= "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-to: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', time()) . "\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php  :

> Each line should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n). Lines should not be
> larger than 70 characters.

Please try to change Heders line separator. Be sure that body is also well formatted. You will find examples in manual.

Good Luck!